# Appropriate place to discuss LEARNING about DNS

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am in the process of setting up a few servers -- Right now we are switching from a managed to un-managed solution. My requirements are "set up web servers" -- check ... "Set up data servers" -- check ... Set up DNS servers .... hmmmmm

Now I am no noob with Linux, and I've even messed around with bind -- But I have been searching all over and can't get a thorough grasp start-to-finish. I'd like to be able to discuss somewhere what my exact needs are, and have possibly have someone either explain what I need, or point me to references that will explain what I need to do.

I know to some this might sound silly, but I've been all over searching, and the information out there is overwhelming. This is a case of too much information can be a bad thing when you need to sift through it all and figure out what you need... The difficult part is, I don't know which information I need! Which Stack Exchange site is the best place for this specific question?!

Comment: The first results of a search for "books about dns" are a good starting point...

Comment: How is that any different than everything I've been reading?  I understand what DNS is -- What I don't know is where to start with my specific needs.  --  Based on Patricks's answer, I am compiling a list of specific needs, and will pose individual questions based on those needs ...

Comment: Don't manage your own DNS. There are lots of providers who can to it cheaply, securely and with greater redundancy that you can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few problems with your request:

- *discuss*: we don't discuss. Meta is the only place open to discussion, but all Q/A sites don't allow discussions;
- *have possibly have someone either explain what I need*: that doesn't fit well in the Q/A style either. We don't build entire start-to-end references or tutorials that covers all. Instead we try to focus on specific questions, with a clear topic and boundaries;
- *or point me to references that will explain what I need to do*: asking for off-site resources is off-topic.

*The difficult part is, I don't know which info I need!* Then start writing down a few narrowed down questions that don't open discussions and don't ask for off-site resources. See if those questions are on-topic anywhere within the network of sites: Hardware Recommendations, Software Recommendation, Unix/Linux, ServerFault, SuperUser, etc.

Comment: Thank you, I will build the server ... Then compile a list of my needs, and ask individual questions based on those needs ...  Thanks for the clarity .. One gets frustrated sometimes in attempting to learn about something, you forget your "due process"!

Answer (score 2):

Such a question isn't appropriate on any site.  SE is a place for specific questions with specific answers, not for entire tutorials on a topic.